# gmap4rails load and add infobox only when marker clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails, gmaps4rails2

I'm using `gmap4rails v2` with `rails 4.1` and instead of loading all of the `infoboxes` at once, which is very inefficient, I would like to only load the contents for the info box of a particular `marker` once that marker is clicked. I came up with the following to select the marker.

```
markers = handler.addMarkers(<%= raw(@hash.to_json) %>);
        _.each(markers, function(marker){
          google.maps.event.addListener(handler.getMap(), 'click', function(){
            marker.infowindow();
          });
        });
```

But I'm not sure how I can send a query to my user table to get the needed attributes for example `User.name`, `User.photo` that will be used in the `infobox`.

The full gmaps handler is here:

```
var handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { markers: { maxRandomDistance: null, clusterer: undefined } }),


  maxZoom = 14;


  handler.buildMap({ 
     provider: {
      mapTypeControl: false,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      streetViewControl: false,
      doClustering: false,
      minZoom: 5  
    },
    internal: {id: 'big_map'}}, 
    function(){

    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%= raw(@hash.to_json) %>);
    _.each(markers, function(marker){
      google.maps.event.addListener(handler.getMap(), 'click', function(){
        marker.infowindow();
      });
    });
    handler.map.centerOn([$("#big_map").data("lat"),$("#big_map").data("lng")]);
    handler.getMap().setZoom(15);
    //handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    //handler.fitMapToBounds();
  });
```

controller which loads marker info:

```
return Gmaps4rails.build_markers(profiles) do |profile, marker|
  marker.lat profile.latitude
  marker.lng profile.longitude
  marker.json({ :id => profile.profile_code })
  # this is how I loaded all markers before: marker.infowindow render_to_string(partial: "info_window", locals: { profile: profile })
  marker.picture({
    url: view_context.image_path( "marker-#{ (profile == current_user.profile) ? 'green' : 'blue' }.png"),
    width:  32,
    height: 32
  })
end
```

Is there any way I could send a partial to the `infowindow()` function like I did in the original markers load as seen below? And if so how would I send the `user.id` to the partial (in my case it's `profile.profile_code` which I set each `marker.id` to equal that I think.

UPDATE:

Ok I now realize I need to make a request to the server, which javascript can't do so I'm going to try to use ajax by using

```
markers = handler.addMarkers(<%= raw(@hash.to_json) %>);
_.each(markers, function(marker){
  google.maps.event.addListener(handler.getMap(), 'click', function(){
    var infowindow = marker.infowindow;
    $.post('<%= load_info_box_url %>', {
    }, function(data){
      infowindow.html(data).name %>)
      infowindow.open(Gmaps.map.map, marker);
    });
  });
});
```

followed by making a load_info_box route and then requesting the necessary data in a controller, sending back html to data!

Comment: what you describe is done by default in the gem

Comment: oh wait, ok I understand, you'd like to avoid the repetitions of partials in the json?

Comment: @apneadiving By default it loads every partial for every infobox for every marker which takes a really long time and is very inefficient.

Comment: I personaly use js templates, would this fit for you?

Comment: @apneadiving hmm not familiar with that. I've added an update with what I'm trying right now.

Comment: if you complain about performance, dont use an ajax call on each click! underscore handles js templates: http://underscorejs.org/#template

Comment: I think the matter here is more having a ton of markers, which make ajax the way to go (especially since js won't do ^^ ). On a side note, hello ben :)

Comment: Hello Olivier! :) yes, the most obvious way to improve perf are: 1) dont load markers in the page directly, serve markers through an api 2) use js templates to get rid of partials redundancy

Comment: @apneadiving so you're saying I could still load all the data at once but using js templates would keep the app from having to load the infobox partials repetitively?

Comment: Apneadiving: Indeed. @Mlennie, you should really consider templating, that way you can only pass json data. Np you're not familiar with it, that's what development is about :) Also, if you add a very large amount of markers, don't forget to try your page on internet explorer, all js engines have not the same performances. Deferring marker creation can also provide a nice visual effect (marker popping one after an other)

Comment: yes correct. just ensure the json contains the necessary variables

Comment: @apneadiving ok thanks guys although it still seems a bit inefficient to load all the infobox data for every infobox if a user will only click on one or two of the markers. The problem is also I have lots of markers on the page, hundreds.

Comment: let me show you how js templating works, will post something

Comment: @pneadiving thanks again it works great. Is there anyway to use a rails partial with template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@apneadiving had a great answer but I found it a bit hard implementing links, conditionals and  styling into javascript templates so I ended up using the ajax approach.

javascript:

```
markers = handler.addMarkers(data.markers);
        _.each(markers, function(json, index){
          json.marker = markers[index]; 
          google.maps.event.addListener(json.marker.getServiceObject(), 'click', function(){
            var infowindow = json.marker.infowindow;

            $.post('<%= load_infobox_url %>', {
              marker_id: data.markers[index].id
            }, function(data){
              infowindow.setContent(data.html);
              infowindow.open(map, google.maps.markers[index]);
            });

          });
        });
```

routes

```
post '/load_infobox', to: 'requests#load_infobox', as: 'load_infobox'
```

controller action:

```
def load_infobox
    profile = Profile.find_by(profile_code: params[:marker_id])
    render json: { html: render_to_string(partial: "info_window", locals: { profile: profile }) }
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

[Check this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/U8sp2n7nQQnGnOYYm9Dx?p=preview)

Basically:

- I create a custom builder
- leverage underscore js templating.

So your json must contain necessary keys but the infowindow html is built only on demand

Comment: Yes thank you. I'm just figuring out if I can use a rails partial in it or if not how I can recreate the partial in the template. But yes it works I'll check it as the answer as soon as its finished. Thanks to you and Olivier.

Comment: actually some gems do allow you to put some templates in JST variables. but is it that necessary...

Comment: ok thanks yeah I have to put a picture in the infobox and there's different formats depending on certain conditions. But I'm trying to put it in by hand right now.

Comment: Thanks again for everything. Do you know the name of some gems that let you do that?

Comment: just incase you feel like being a hero once again...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454909/cannot-render-content-with-handlebars-and-rails

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the post and update the answer.